# how to show the convergence of an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, recursive-algorithms

I have two unknown variables  x and y which are non linear equations to be solved.

\begin{eqnarray}
y=\frac {|\sin(2x+\theta)|}{\sin x\sqrt{A+2B\cos(2x+\theta)}} \nonumber \\
x=\arccos\bigg( -\frac{1}{2(Dr^{y/M}+1)} \bigg) 
\end{eqnarray}

I have developed some iterative process algorithm to calculate the answer.

simulations show that the algorithm converges, but the problem is how do I prove this mathematically. What techniques need to be used?

Algorithm:

given $x(0)=2\pi/3$ and $\epsilon=10^{-6}$ and $A,B,D,r,M,\theta$ are constants

i=0

1. compute $y$:
   \begin{equation}
   y(i)=\frac {|\sin(2x(i)+\theta)|}{\sin x(i)\sqrt{A+2B\cos(2x(i)+\theta)}} \nonumber 
   \end{equation}
2. update $x$:
   \begin{equation}
   x(i+1)=\arccos\bigg( -\frac{1}{2(Dr^{y(i)/M}+1)} \bigg)  \nonumber
   \end{equation}

   i=i+1

repeat till $|x(i+1)-x(i) |<\epsilon$

Comment: I do not think that you can prove that such an algorithm converges as you set it. Why don't you solve simultaneously two equations for two unknowns x and y ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Greetings, I want to study it numerically. Which interests me.

Comment: Looks like a fixed point iteration to me.

Comment: @PavelJiranek it is hard to prove in that way,

Comment: What is hard to prove in what way?

Comment: @PavelJiranek DO you have any examples on how to prove $f$ is Lipschitz continuous?  or can you recommend me some notes or papers.

Comment: @PavelJiranek also $x_{k+1}=f(x_{k})$ is a messy equation

Comment: @PavelJiranek I think hint is not an answer.

Comment: @Harry 1) Hint is certainly better than nothing and may provide clues to the OP on how to at least try to solve their problem. 2) Yes, $x_{k+1}=f(x_k)$ is messy, I hope you don't expect me to make it nice or differentiate it myself :-D. 3) I don't like when people are urging me to answer their questions especially when my brain's off during Sunday and Monday at 6AM I'm still sleeping.

Comment: @PavelJiranek I meant sometimes people put hints as the answer to get more experience in this site. But I know, you genuinely want to help people. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @PavelJiranek it is hard to prove in the way you have suggested my friend. Do you know any other methods? If so that would be really helpful.

Comment: @Harry Do you have more context about the constants? In particular do you have $\sin x\sqrt{A+2B\cos(2x+\theta)}\neq 0$ for every $x\in[-1,1]$?

Answer (score 3):

This is a fixed point iteration, which, given an equation $x=f(x)$ you want to solve for $x$, seeks the solution by an iterative process $x_{k+1}=f(x_k)$ starting from some initial guess $x_0$.

A usual approach to determine if the fixed point iteration converges is to verify whether $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with the Lipschitz constant smaller than one.

Comment: The answer is not clear and that is too generalized.

Comment: Just put the expression for $y(i)$ to that for $x(i+1)$ and you get exactly what I wrote above. Do you expect a hint or a complete solution?

Comment: how do I show $f$ is Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: hint is not a complete answer. You could comment your hint.

Comment: "how do I show $f$ is Lipschitz continuous?" e.g., by showing that $f$ has a bounded derivative: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Properties

Comment: how do i take $f$ out from $f(x_{k})$

Answer (score 2):

Plugging the expression of $y$ into that of $x$, you have a single equation in a single unknown $x=f(x)$, which you could solve by [classical methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) such as the secant, regula falsi, Newton, Brent... alternatively to fixed-point. Some of these methods give you guarantees on convergence.

A first step is to observe the shape of $f(x)$ for typical values of the free parameters, as a general study risks to be arduous.

Note that you can absorb the two parameters $M$ and $r$ in $A$ and $B$.

Interestingly, you can rewrite the second relation as

$$y=a\ln(-2\sec(x)-1)+b,$$

which has a simple behavior (two vertical asymptotes and a single extremum in the middle, repeating periodically).